# vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker input typing permission block without disabled & readonly

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using `vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker` in my project. It's works fine.

But I faced an error in this picker input typing time. So I need to block that input typing.

If I use `disabled` & `readonly` the focus is not working. So the picker popup will not show. (picker functionalities do not trigger)

Is there a better solution?

Comment: can you show the HTML tree of this component when it's successfully rendered please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is use to prevent input typing. you need to paste the below code to your component `mounted` function. because after render datepicker keydown listener need to start. i think this will help

```
mounted () {
        $(`#${DATE_PICKER_ID}`).keydown((ev) => {
          ev.preventDefault();
        });
    },
```